# When a cell value changes, copy the column from where the cell value changed to another sheet at the same range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

For example, if in the range of A:A only cell A8 change then copy D4:D8 and paste it as value in sheet "ADP" at the same place i.e. D4:D8.

For that I have tried the following macro

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.range = "A:A" Then
        Call copy_paste_as_value
    End If
End Sub


Sub copy_paste_as_value()
    Range("d4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Sheets("ADP").Activate
    Range("B4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("C4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

I want to copy only that data against which cell value changes, but it copies the whole table to another sheet.

main issue for me is to figure out which cell changed and copy data from that column only from which cell value changed.

here, it's to be noted that data should be copied only if there is change in range A:A, if change in any other cell than copy paste not required.

any help will be appriciated.
thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything other than just record a macro? A good start would be to check if `Target` consist of one cell plus if it intersects with column A.

Comment: to be honestly,as i am begginer, currently i do not have much knowledge about it, but tryig to learn. if you can help, it ll be appriciated.

Comment: it is not clear, why if A8 is changed, D8-D4 should be copied? If A11 - then D11-D7 should be copied? If B10 is changed - nothing is copied?

Comment: YES, you are right, change should be in range A:A only if any change other than range A:A then nothing should be copied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim wsSou As Worksheet, wsDes As Worksheet

    'Set the worksheets to avoid conflicts
    Set wsSou = Target.Worksheet
    Set wsDes = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ADP")

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then

        wsDes.Range(wsDes.Cells(Target.Row, 4), wsDes.Cells(Target.Row, 9)).Value = wsSou.Range(wsSou.Cells(Target.Row, 4), wsSou.Cells(Target.Row, 9)).Value

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: YES,  it's working very well, thank you so much for giving time & putting efforts

Comment: kindly, can you please suggest me that, where do i have to make changes if i want to paste range D4:I4, instead of D4:D8

Comment: @Arshitpatel it s a good idea to `Set` both worksheets, to use `Target.Count = 1` to avoid errors when you select multi cells.

Comment: When i have replaced with new formula, outcome of macro was not as expected, cell value A10 CHANGED but value pasted in cell D4:D4 IN sheet "ADP"

Comment: AND i want to paste in D4:I4 whereas edited ans. is for D4:H4. THANK YOU.

Comment: @Arshitpatel i try the code and when i change the value in `A10` line was paste in `D6:H6` which is the correct right?

Comment: what is required is, when i change value in A10 range of D10:I10 should be paste, & suppose value in A11 change range of D11:I11 should be paste & so on...like wise...

Comment: @Arshitpatel finally i get your point. To busy day, see the updated answer.

Comment: 100% perfectly working now. thank you so much for finally resolving this issue. thanks for giving your valuable time and sharing knowledge. thanks by heart.

Comment: Glad to hear that i help!

Comment: suppose in sheet if there is any change at any cell in sheet, then macro should run, then what should be the macro? kindly can you help on this? present situation is, if there is change in range A:A then only macro runs. thank you.

Comment: Remove `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then` & `End If`

Comment: yes ok. done. again thank you from bottom of my heart for helping.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the relative range is consistent, try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim r As Range

If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row > 4 Then
    Set r = Target.Offset(-4, 3).Resize(5)
    Worksheets("ADP").Range(r.Address).Value = r.Value
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: YES, it's working very well, thank you for putting efforts & investing your valuable time.