# Change range in coding

Tags: excel, vba

I have coding where range of D4:D8 is selected but i want to get range D4:I4 instead of D4:D8.

I have tried following code

```
Dim wsSou As Worksheet, wsDes As Worksheet

wsDes.Range(wsDes.Cells(Target.Row - 4, 4), wsDes.Cells(Target.Row, 
4)).Value = wsSou.Range(wsSou.Cells(Target.Row - 4, 4), 
wsSou.Cells(Target.Row, 4)).Value
```

above code is as per range D4:D8, Whereas i want to ge range D4:I4.

thank you.

Comment: This question is directly related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56458158/when-a-cell-value-changes-copy-the-column-from-where-the-cell-value-changed-to). Have you tried changing around the numbers that make up the cells row and column?

Comment: just change a 4 to 0 or 1!

Comment: yes, i have tried a lot, but strangely it's not working. i don't know the exact reason

Comment: if you have understand the problem, and can throw some light on it, then it will be appriciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the `cells` function, the first parameter is the row, and the second is the column, so keep the first part the same (same row), and change the second instead (changing column D->I):

```
Dim wsSou As Worksheet, wsDes As Worksheet

wsDes.Range(wsDes.Cells(Target.Row - 4, 4), wsDes.Cells(Target.Row - 4, 9)).Value = _
wsSou.Range(wsSou.Cells(Target.Row - 4, 4), wsSou.Cells(Target.Row - 4, 9)).Value
```

Comment: actually, i have tried above code, which should logically work, but id doesn't for detailed understanding of problem, i would like to request you to refer to given link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56458158/when-a-cell-value-changes-copy-the-column-from-where-the-cell-value-changed-to)